# Inside a service, can i do sync http request without freezing the app UI?

Tags: android, android-service

Inside a service, can I do sync network request without freezing the app UI ? I heard that services work on the same thread as the app ui thread (I heard this, but I'm not sure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android service will be using the same UI Thread. So you cannot make a network request directly from the UI thread.

You can make synchronous requests by creating a new thread and making the UI thread waiting - NOT Recommended as it will hang the UI eventually results in "ANR"

The best solution is to rewrite you app logic to work in async manner... :)

You can also check about [Intent Services](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) which uses worker thread. But again its async

Comment: This is wrong. A `Service` can start threads itself. the `Service` doesn't **run on the UI thread**. Some **methods** of a `Service` are called on the UI thread. These statements are misleading.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. May I ask you whether we can create Threads in Activity and run some code inside that thread? If yes, does that means Activity is not running in UI Thread? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html A quote from this : "Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process." UI thread is the Main Thread!!

Comment: Of course you can create threads within an `Activity` and run code inside those threads. An instance of the `Activity` is an object. It doesn't run on any thread. Think of it like this: An object takes up **space**. Methods of the object's class are called on a specific thread of execution. Threads represent **time**, not space. An object does not exist on any thread, it just exists in memory. This is a very important concept and one that gets developers in a lot of trouble if they do not understand it. The documentation you linked to is incorrect and misleading. neither services, nor other...

Comment: ...application objects run on the main thread. What is important here is that certain methods of `Service`, `Activity`, etc. are called by the Android framework on the main (UI) thread. This is important to know, but it does not mean that the object in question "runs on the main thread", nor does it prevent the developer from creating new (background) threads and executing other methods on those threads. I realize this may sound pedantic, but it is an extremely important programming concept and IMHO we must be pedantic about how we discuss certain things. This is one of my pet peeves.

Comment: Also, please don't get me started on how much of the Android documentation is incorrect, inaccurate, misleading, missing, or just plain wrong. I could sing volumes about that!

Comment: Thanks for your comments and so we both agree to the fact that the callbacks to activity and service is been done on Main Thread by Android? Usually we perform operations based on these callbacks in the Service and that makes service to run on UI thread (if we are not spinning new threads). Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: The only other way to execute the callbacks on these service in another thread from outside is to create an object of this service and call the methods in another thread which makes the Service a plain Java class without any advantage of being an Android Service. So to me, the Android Documentations seems to be correct!

Comment: No, actually if you use a bound `Service` both the calls to the `Service` and the callbacks are also made on background (worker) threads. So, no. The documentation is not correct, because an object does not run on a specific thread. This confuses 2 concepts: space and time. The documented calls from the Android framework (like `onCreate()`, `onResume()`, `onStartCommand()`, etc.) are made on the main (UI) thread, unless the documentation explicitly states otherwise. This does NOT mean that a `Service` runs on the main (UI) thread, nor does it imply that an `Activity` runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

**Synchronous requests trigger app crashes on Android 4.0 or newer. You’ll run into the `NetworkOnMainThreadException` error.**

Synchronous methods are executed on the main thread. That means the UI blocks during request execution and no interaction is possible for this period.

Answer (score 0):

The `onStartCommand()` of a `Service` is called on the main thread. However, in `onStartCommand()` you can simply start a background thread and do all of your network I/O there. Background threads can block without causing any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this guide you in the right direction

Caution: A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise. If your service is going to perform any CPU-intensive work or blocking operations, such as MP3 playback or networking, you should create a new thread within the service to complete that work. By using a separate thread, you can reduce the risk of Application Not Responding (ANR) errors, and the application's main thread can remain dedicated to user interaction with your activities.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Executing long running Sync operation application in main loop via service is a risk tradeoff.